# Is there any way to update an old app with Xcode 7 and the iOS9.1 SDK and use the awesome auto scaling for the iPhone 6/6+?

Tags: xcode, ios9, xcode7, ios9.1

I have an older app that was designed without Auto Layout, with three storyboards for iPhone 4, iPhone 5, and iPads. When iPhone 6s came out, all seemed fine, as it scaled up the iPhone 5 layouts.

I'm getting asked to update a few code-related things in the app, but no budget to go in and create iPhone 6 layouts, or switch the old storyboards over to use Auto Layout and Size Classes, which would be a considerable amount of work.

With the iOS9 SDK, I get black bars at the top and bottom on the iPhone 6 and 6+ by default when publishing. I've read about adding new launch images to enable the native resolutions, which then causes my layout to be scaled down and not taking up the entire screen (because of no Auto Layout).

Is there any way to publish with XCode 7 and the iOS9 SDK and use the awesome auto scaling that it is currently using on the old version? All views function through a UINavigationViewController. Is there some hackery I can do to scale that view up?

Comment: @rmaddy did you ever read my question, or just mark it duplicate based on the title? I'm not asking WHY it has black bars at the top and bottom, I'm asking if there is a way to fix it without having to use AutoLayout and reconstruct my views.

Comment: Of course I read it. You need to provide the proper launch images to support the 4" iPhone.

Comment: Did you miss the part where I said? "I've read about adding new launch images to enable the native resolutions, which then causes my layout to be scaled down and not taking up the entire screen (because of no Auto Layout)."

Comment: I didn't say to add iPhone 6 launch images.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the solution from the  issue in which you say I'm a "duplicate." That issue's solution says to add a Storyboard file. If I do this, it shrinks all my layouts on the iPhone 6 so all the text is too small and layout is just justified from the top left of the screen. I'd like it to maintain the same exact sizing as the iPhone 5, like iOS did automatically to the app when the new devices came out.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, just add the 4" launch image.